# remove the right click menu in flash 9

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, menu, cs3, right-click

Is it possible, using actionscript 3 to disable the right click menu?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: An API has been added for this in Flash Player 11.2, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12519480/1587219

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in AS3 (Adobe probably never put support in there because it would prevent the user from accessing the security settings).

There are ways to do it through HTML, etc.

Check out http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=175669

Answer (score 24):

You can use:

```
stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;
```

to hide everything but the settings option.

Comment: @brenjt No, this hides also the Flash Player Menu. I like the `myContextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();` better.

Answer (score 19):

Starting with Flash Player 11.2, it's possible now to override the behavior for the right button click on the mouse, e.g.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function(e:Event){});
```

Here is the [corresponding entry in the ActionScript 3 reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#RIGHT_CLICK).

Comment: Now **THIS** is the best news!

Comment: This crashes Flash Player for me. Not even a runtime error that I can catch. It just breaks. I'm targeting Flash Player 21.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide everything except for the Settings item, as said by Lain.

By the way: If you need to customize it you can use the [ContextMenu class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html) from the flash.ui package. Call hideBuiltInItems on it first to hide everything except for the Settings and then assign it to the menu property of the object you want to use the menu for (or root for the entire applet).

FYI, there is a nice tutorial about it that you can find [here](http://www.albinoblacksheep.com/tutorial/contextmenu)

Answer (score 2):

this code would also work

```
var newMenu=new ContextMenu();
newMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
this.menu = newMenu;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello a couple of years later.
I had the same problem but while using a touch-screen. If you keep the pointing device (my finger) touching the screen for more than a second the "right-click menu" will show up. I soved it going to the control panel under Windows7, "Pencil and input devices", Touch Tab, Actions, Turn off actions for "Keep pressed".

My windows is in spanish and the names are problably a bit different but I'm sure you'll know which button is which.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better option

```
_level1._y = 195;
var myMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
myMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
_root.menu = myMenu;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with `wmode` `opaque` then you can intercept the right click at browser level as done here:

http://www.uza.lt/rightclick/