# Disable printing in adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flexbuilder

I am building my website in adobe flex(i  am n00b). I have some photographs which I would like to make sure that people cannot print.

I do understand that it is not possible to completely stop users from printing. But atleast disable the context menu or just the print option and the copy option.

Any and all things about this is helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377033/remove-the-right-click-menu-in-flash-9

Answer (score 2):

People can always make a PrintScreen of the browser window and then paste in paint and print.
So you cannot eliminate all the possibilities of printing the images.

The best scenario is to have a license agreement and people are not allowed to download/print the images.