# How to disable Rewind/Forward options?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, cs3

You know when you right-click on a scene and a bunch of options pop up? How do you disable the rewind and forward options (in-case a user accidentally presses on one of those options) because it screws my whole Flash game up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove the right click menu in flash 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377033/remove-the-right-click-menu-in-flash-9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable most of the context menu with

```
stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;
```

This will still leave the Settings and About sections though

There was a trick to completely remove the right click menu by catching up right click events on the stage, no idea if it still works with the current flash player versions:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, doNothing);

private function doNothing(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    //do nothing...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Highly appreciate it!

Comment: I wonder if adding `e.preventDefault()` should be used in `doNothing()` because otherwise it does nothing also to prevent showing the menu.